# Replacement Bulb For Under Cabinet Lighting

Tags: light-fixture

Have under cabinet lighting and need to replace burned out bulbs.  The bulbs are model G9 120v 25W halogen (ceramic base).  Would like to replace with LED bulbs.  What replacement bulb would work? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

> **What replacement bulb would work?**

Any LED G9 120V bulb rated less than 25W. A LED bulb of around 6W probably has a brightness (see its Lumens rating) similar to a 25W Halogen.

---

Glossary:

- Lumens are a measure of luminous flux and are a better guide to brightness than Watts.
- Watts are essentially a measure of how much heat the bulb emits, not light.

Comment: Plus 1, it may be useful to add G9  to your glossary in order to explain that it is the fitment specification. I.E. the base and why it matters in order to replace it.